# How to convert a Datetime string to a current culture datetime string

Tags: c#

I have string say "12/1/2011" in English US culture my current machine culture is English Uk which is "dd/mm/yyyy" format. How to convert the 12/1/2011 to 1/12/2011. I have tried the below format.

```
System.DateTime.Parse(result,System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture)
              .ToString(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern)
```

but i could not able to see any output.

-Lokesh.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTime and CultureInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797727/datetime-and-cultureinfo)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
DateTimeFormatInfo usDtfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;
DateTimeFormatInfo ukDtfi = new CultureInfo("en-GB", false).DateTimeFormat;
string result = Convert.ToDateTime("12/01/2011", usDtfi).ToString(ukDtfi.ShortDatePattern);
```

This will do the trick ^^

Comment: Sorry, this is not working.DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
        dtfi.ShortDatePattern = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
        dtfi.DateSeparator = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator;
        result = Convert.ToDateTime(result, dtfi).ToString(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);

Comment: Because when you set `dtfi.ShortDatePattern = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePat­tern;` it will get your current DatePattern in your machine, not the pattern of the original date string :)

Comment: If you set the region and language settings as English[uk], the short date pattern is dd/MM/yyyy.

Comment: {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}

Answer (score 10):

This works for me:

```
string myTime = DateTime.Parse("12/1/2011")
                        .ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var culture = new CultureInfo( "en-GB" );
var dateValue = new DateTime( 2011, 12, 1 );
var result = dateValue.ToString( "d", culture ) );
```

Comment: CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
        System.DateTime dt = System.DateTime.Parse(result);
        result = dt.ToString("d", culture); I tried this but its not working. Can you let me know why?

Answer (score 5):

```
DateTime dateValue;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
DateTimeStyles styles = DateTimeStyles.None;
DateTime.TryParse(datetimestring,culture, styles, out dateValue);
```

Comment: Man you saved my day, was looking everywhere to try and determine how I can set CUltureInfo on a variable level (without altering CurrentCulture) and could not find it under Date DataType's properties, methods etc... .TryParse wasn't available under a typical Date datatypes extension methods. When you showed me DateTime.TryParse, I realized it's outside of the available extension methods for Date and DateTime. Any reason why they've done it like this? Since you can declare an empty date & set itself with dateString + CultureInfo if TryParse was available in an extension method to Date type!???

Comment: You should use TryParse method in DateTime Conversion for safely easily conversion.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static DateTime ConvertDateTime(string Date)
    {
        DateTime date=new DateTime();                        
        try
        {
            string CurrentPattern = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;                
            string[] Split = new string[] {"-","/",@"\","."};
            string[] Patternvalue = CurrentPattern.Split(Split,StringSplitOptions.None);
            string[] DateSplit = Date.Split(Split,StringSplitOptions.None);
            string NewDate = "";
            if (Patternvalue[0].ToLower().Contains("d") == true && Patternvalue[1].ToLower().Contains("m")==true && Patternvalue[2].ToLower().Contains("y")==true)
            {
                NewDate = DateSplit[1] + "/" + DateSplit[0] + "/" + DateSplit[2];
            }
            else if (Patternvalue[0].ToLower().Contains("m") == true && Patternvalue[1].ToLower().Contains("d")==true && Patternvalue[2].ToLower().Contains("y")==true)
            {
                NewDate = DateSplit[0] + "/" + DateSplit[1] + "/" + DateSplit[2];
            }
            else if (Patternvalue[0].ToLower().Contains("y") == true && Patternvalue[1].ToLower().Contains("m")==true && Patternvalue[2].ToLower().Contains("d")==true)
            {
                NewDate = DateSplit[2] + "/" + DateSplit[0] + "/" + DateSplit[1];
            }
            else if (Patternvalue[0].ToLower().Contains("y") == true && Patternvalue[1].ToLower().Contains("d")==true && Patternvalue[2].ToLower().Contains("m")==true)
            {
                NewDate = DateSplit[2] + "/" + DateSplit[1] + "/" + DateSplit[0];
            }
            date = DateTime.Parse(NewDate, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {

        }

        return date;

    }
```

Comment: please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable

Comment: @kleopatra you can also do it

Comment: Also consider adding some kind of description.

Comment: @j0k sure I could - but I don't like spoon-feeding everybody all the time, they can learn doing it themselves, don't they :-)

Comment: why empty catch and finally?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,

```
DateTimeFormatInfo usDtfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;
DateTimeFormatInfo ukDtfi = new CultureInfo("en-GB", false).DateTimeFormat;
string result = Convert.ToDateTime("26/09/2015",ukDtfi).ToString(usDtfi.ShortDatePattern);
```

Comment: This is no different from the currently accepted answer.

Comment: @helix  I just swap  the culture objects, because the existing answer results an error for me, I have no sufficient point to edit the existing answer.

Comment: Maybe because the existing answer converts from US to UK and yours converts from UK to US.

Comment: @helix please do check both of the answers with these days '26/09/2015' and '12/01/2011'