# DateTime and CultureInfo

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo

I have this in my code:

```
var date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And when my current cultur is dutch (`nl-NL`) instead of May 1st I get January 5th.

I think the error is in the second parameter `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss`.

Is there a way to fix this using the `CultureInfo` class?

Comment: Yes, don't use ParseExact but Parse!!! With ParseExact you're asking a specific ordering for date parts, given culture is used only for strings and separators.

Comment: Where is `date` coming from? How is it created?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureinfo =
        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nl-NL");
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date, cultureinfo);
```

Comment: And what about when the culture is en-us? Will I have to code for every single language there is out there?

Comment: You can use the system setting wtih CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

Comment: If you use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture as @PuiHoLam said, be aware that it will use the Culture where your code is running

Comment: Well, the only time you'd receive culture specific date is offline apps. For online services, communications should be done with UTC.

Answer (score 6):

Use `CultureInfo` class to change your culture info.

```
var dutchCultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL");
var date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", dutchCultureInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

`InvariantCulture` is similar to `en-US`, so i would use the correct `CultureInfo` instead:

```
var dutchCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL");
var date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", dutchCulture);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/DfiVQa)

> And what about when the culture is en-us? Will I have to code for
>   every single language there is out there?

If you want to know how to display the date in another culture like "en-us", you can use `date1.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))`.

Comment: And what about when the culture is en-us? Will I have to code for every single language there is out there?

Comment: @Srcee: What do you mean? If the format string is "dd.MM.yyyy", it will never be culture en-us. If you instead mean how to display the date in another culture, then it's another question. You can use `date1.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it..It will work

string text="15/03/2021";

DateTime.ParseExact(text, "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);