# How to set name of month with indonesian language using Culture types

Tags: c#

I have a data from DateTime.
with output = "10 October 2014".
and I want output like this = "10 Oktober 2014".

This is my test code:

```
lblTglSuratKeluar.Text = suratKeluarc.TglSurat.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy"); //10 October 2014
var A = lblTglSuratKeluar.Text.Substring(3); //October 2014
var B = A.Substring(0, A.Length - 5); //October
```

=>So, how to use culturestype ??

```
 CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures &  ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
 string testOutPut = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, cultures.Select(c => String.Format("{0}:  {1}", B, c.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(1))).ToArray());
```

please, help me...

Thanks...

Comment: Is your *actual* issue how to retrieve the [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance for Indonesia?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DateTime and CultureInfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797727/datetime-and-cultureinfo)

Comment: you should use something like: date.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("id-ID"));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you should use:

```
lblTglSuratKeluar.Text = suratKeluarc.TglSurat.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("id-ID"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13797727/824495).

You should use "id-ID" CultureInfo and parse your string into a DateTime object using the culture info.

```
// Get the default formatted date
string indonesianDate =  suratKeluarc.TglSurat.ToString();

// Parse the date string using the indonesian cultureinfo
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureinfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("id-ID");
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(indonesianDate, cultureinfo);

// Get your formatted string.
lblTglSuratKeluar.Text = dt.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy", cultureinfo);
```

You can find the other culture codes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: If you believe the question is a duplicate, then you should mark it as such

Comment: "date" => the name 'date' doesnt exist in current context ??? when i change 'date' with 'indoneisanDate' not error, but the return is same = 10 October 2014. not 10 Oktober 2014

Comment: I've updated my answer, tested on a console app, gives the expected output. Please test again.