# How to Add one day to hijri date?

Tags: c#

I am trying to adjust hijri date by adding one or two days to current date as in normal gregorian date but seems to be different in C#, this is my code giving me an error:

> string does not contain a definition for AddDays.

```
var HijriDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd dd MMMM yyyy", new CultureInfo("ar-SA"));
var NewHijriDate = HijriDate.AddDays(1);
Labelhijridate.Text = NewHijriDate;
```

Comment: of course, it will not work because the type of HijriDate is a string and not DateTime
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13797790/13124794) **see here**

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `.ToString` early.. Do DateTime operations before calling `.ToString`

```
var HijriDate = DateTime.Now;
var NewHijriDate = HijriDate.AddDays(1);
Labelhijridate.Text = NewHijriDate.ToString("dddd dd MMMM yyyy", new CultureInfo("ar-SA"));
```

Comment: Many thanks Mohammad chokran.