# Convert.ToDateTime: how to set format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I use convert like:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(value)
```

but i need convert date to format like "mm/yy".
I'm looking for something like this:

```
var format = "mm/yy";
Convert.ToDateTime(value, format)
```

Comment: `DateTime` objects don't have a format defined. You can output the DataTime in a format, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should probably use either [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee1y0t7.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) instead. They allow you to specify specific formats. I personally prefer the `Try`-versions since I think they produce nicer code for the error cases.

Comment: datetime.paeseExact("12/12", "mm/yy", Cul..)={01/01/2012 00:12:00};

Comment: but i expect {01/12/12} or {12/12}

Comment: @Refael you need to read up on [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). `mm` is minutes, `MM` is years.

Comment: I think you mean `MM` is _Months_

Answer (score 15):

If `value` is a `string` in that format and you'd like to convert it into a `DateTime` object, you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) static method:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(value, format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Example:

```
string value = "12/12";
var myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "MM/yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);

Console.WriteLine(myDate.ToShortDateString());
```

Result:

```
2012-12-01
```

Comment: i try this:  string value = "12/12"; format = "mm/yy"; then datetime.paeseExact(value, format, Cul..) = return {01/01/2012 00:12:00}. why ?

Comment: So `DateTime.ParseExact(value, "mm/yy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);` should work.

Comment: i expect to {01/12/12} or {12/12}

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` doesn't have a format.  the format only applies when you're turning a `DateTime` into a string, which happens implicitly you show the value on a form, web page, etc.

Look at *where* you're displaying the DateTime and set the format there (or amend your question if you need additional guidance).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Convert.ToDateTime is it is shown at [How to convert a Datetime string to a current culture datetime string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590180/how-to-convert-a-datetime-string-to-a-current-culture-datetime-string/5590213#5590213)

```
DateTimeFormatInfo usDtfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;

var result = Convert.ToDateTime("12/01/2011", usDtfi)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    string test = "01-12-12";
    try{
         DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(test);
         test = dateTime.ToString("dd/yyyy");
    }
    catch (FormatException exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
    }
```

Where test will be equal to "12/2012"

Hope it helps!

Please read [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).