# Returning only date from ToDateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssms

Heads up, I'm fairly new to working with Databases so this is an elementary level question.

I'm trying to pull the date from the SQL Database but it returns both the date and time. In SQL, I have the type as date so it isn't recording any time yet it continues to return something like 01/12/2002 12:00:00. I'm assuming the issue is in my C# code by using the `ToDateTime()` method since it is meant to return time as well.

All I want is to pull the date in MM/dd/yyyy formatting.

I've looked all over and have tried countless suggestions I've found on here and other sites but still, nothing has solved the problem. I've tried TryParse, converting to a string, and a few other ways to try and work it out.

Thanks for any help you all can provide. Much appreciated!

```c#
while (reader.Read())
{
    EventModel eventModel = new EventModel();
    eventModel.EventType = reader["EventType"].ToString();
    eventModel.Title = reader["Title"].ToString();
    eventModel.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Date"]);
    eventModel.Location = reader["Location"].ToString();
    eventModel.Company = reader["Company"].ToString();

    allEvents.AddLast(eventModel);
}
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EventType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Location] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Company] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: What's the *SQL Database*? E.g. Oracle's DATE datatype is actually a timestamp. In Standard SQL `CAST(timestampcolumn AS DATE)` strips off the time portiton.

Comment: Just posted what I have in SQL above

Comment: Please tag the DBMS. Is it SQL Server? Your tag `sql` simply indicates that we're taking about Structured Query Language.

Comment: Try `SELECT convert(varchar(10), [Date], 101)` to let the database do the conversion froom DATE to string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert.ToDateTime: how to set format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203534/convert-todatetime-how-to-set-format)

Comment: @dnoeth do I write that command in the Sql panel?

Comment: @derloopkat Tried some suggestions but it's still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said you want to pull the date *formatted*. The `DateTime` object doesn't contain any formatting. If no time is supplied, then the `DateTime`'s time component will default to midnight. You need to add the formatting to display the date component only.

You have a few options. You could format the date straight out of the database, but you didn't post your SQL query. Without adjusting your query, you could do something as simple as changing your `eventModel.Date` to a `String` instead of a `DateTime` and then:

```cs
eventModel.Date = DateTime.Parse(reader["Date"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

The `ToString()` function formats the output the way you want it to display. Maybe you tried calling `ToString()` without the formatting parameter. I changed the `Convert.ToDateTime` to `DateTime.Parse` as that is what `Convert.ToDateTime` will call anyway.

On a side note, take a look at Entity Framework for working with the database, it's a great time saver.

Comment: I changed eventModel.Date to a string and used this to line and seems to be working correctly. ```eventModel.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Date"].ToString()).ToShortDateString(); ```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below to return mm/dd/yyyy

```
   eventModel.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Date"].ToString()).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: says I can't convert type string to datetime

Comment: Is the reader returning a valid date? (it wont work if its null) Also what type is eventModel.Date?

Comment: It's a valid date and they type was Datetime but I just changed it to string and now it's working.