# how to convert label.text= dr["column'].tostring to datetime?

Tags: c#

i have try many converting techniques but always failed

Like: 
I have in

```
[btnIN button]
lbltimein.text = dr["column_name"].toString();


[btnout button]
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(lbltimein.text);
```

Comment: What is the string value of `lbltimein.Text`, You may need [Custom DateTime Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) with `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`

Comment: What does the string that you're trying to convert look like?

Comment: See if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590180

Comment: in lbltimein.text it has the timein Time in database.
i need to convert that lbltime.text to datetime to come up with time out and total hours of work

Comment: Please be more specific about your input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: If there is an error converting, then the date string may not be in a convertable date format.  We need to actually see the string thats stored in `lbltimein.text`

Comment: i have my timein Time in lbltimein.text and i want it to convert to date so that i can compute the totalhours of work

Comment: the string of 12:01:35: AM in lbltimeine.text this string is inside my datebase

Comment: string s = lblDueDate.Text;
                    DateTime DueDate = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);

Itry this but its getting me error. i think my error is from the format of date but only i need is the time to format? how can i do that?

And I tris the result is the same error:
string s = lblDueDate.Text;
                    DateTime DueDate = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the Format in which user inputs the `Date` Value

For example if the format i `dd-MM-yyyy`

Try This:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(lbltimein.Text,"dd-MM-yyyy",
       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ;
```

**EDIT:** from the comments if you have the time in format of `HH:mm:ss`
You can Split it based on semicolon and assign it to `TimeSpan` constructor to get the total hours.

```
var time = lbltimein.Text.Split(':');
TimeSpan time=new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(time[0]),
                             Convert.ToInt32(time[1]),Convert.ToInt32(time[2]));
double totalHours = time.TotalHours;
```

**EDIT 2:** if you have format like : `08:00:00 AM`

Try This:

```
var inputtime = lbltimein.Text;
TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(inputtime.Substring(0,2)),
                            Convert.ToInt32(inputtime.Substring(3, 2)), 
                            Convert.ToInt32(inputtime.Substring(6, 2)));
double totalHours = time.TotalHours;
```

Comment: the format of my lbltimein in my database is like 08:00:00 AM

Comment: its ok now. how can i compute for the timeout and subtract it to the lbltimein.text to get the total hours correctly. because when i click the btntimeout button ill get the lbltimein.text and subtract it to the datetime now so that i can get the total hrs.

Comment: the edit2 is working is the Timespan time is for lbltimein.text?
how can i subtract it to the current time?

Comment: string s = lblDueDate.Text;
                    DateTime DueDate = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);

Itry this but its getting me error. i think my error is from the format of date but only i need is the time to format? how can i do that?

And I tris the result is the same error:
string s = lblDueDate.Text;
                    DateTime DueDate = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);

Comment: DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(lbltimein.Text,"dd-MM-yyyy",
       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ;
DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
Timespan ts = dt2 - dt;

but im getting the error of the 1st line says that:
FormatException was unhandled :String was not recognized as a valid

Comment: what is the meening of substring(0,2)(3,2)(6,2)

Comment: substring(0,2) gives the hours,substring(3,2) gives the minutes,substring(6,2) gives the seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Parse(dr["column_name"].ToString())
```

should do the trick if your string is in a valid DateTime format.

If your not sure of the format, you can also try this to determine if your string can be converted. I prefer this method since it gives you a chance to handle bad input without try/catch blocks.

```
DateTime OutputTime = new DateTime();
if(DateTime.TryParse(dr["column_name"].ToString(),out OutputTime))
{
 ///manipulate output datetime here if successful
}
else
{
///figure out why the conversion failed / handle error
}
```

Comment: I got this error where i try it.
FormatException was unhandled :String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: So your input is not in a standard DateTime format. You'll need to change the text of the string to match a valid DateTime format. What is the exact string you are trying to parse?

Comment: its only a time like this "hh:mm:ss tt"